# Controller doesn't load, no errors from Apache or CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm sure this is a simple mistake on my part. I'm trying to demo ci to a friend and we created a simple controller that looks like this:

```
<?php

class Customerlookup extends CI_Controller {

    //constructor for this class
    public function __construct()
    {

        parent::__construct();      
        $this->load->model('customerlookup_model');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        echo 'test';
    }
    public function loadcustomers()
    {
        $data['cust'] = this->customerlookup_model->get_customers();
        $this->load->view('customerlookup',$data);
    }

}
```

And here's what the model looks like:

```
<?php 
class Customerlookup_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::Model();
        $this->load->database();
    }

    public function get_customers()
    {
        $query = $this->db->get('customer');
        return $query->result_array();
    }
}
```

If I try to test this out by doing either:

```
localhost/myapp/index.php/customerlookup/loadcustomers
```

or

```
localhost/myapp/index.php/customerlookup/
```

nothing happens and no errors appear and no data or messages either. We are using the latest CodeIgniter (2.1.3).

Any suggestion?

Comment: Title is a bit misleading. Blank screen doesn't mean controllers isn't loading.

Comment: apache is web server.  also i tried adding an echo statement in the controller's constructor but it never appears.

Comment: is your rewrite_url enabled?

Comment: yes, i've tried changing from none to all and then restarting apache2 but that hasn't changed anything...

Comment: can it print out anything from the controller even a simple echo ?

Answer (score 0):

i found the problem. php errors were not turned on.  there were some syntax problems.  checked the apache error log and figured out that the errors were just not being displayed

thanks for the help guys

Answer (score 0):

you are missing with your url helper

$this->load->helper('url');

into your

class Customerlookup extends CI_Controller {

```
//constructor for this class
public function __construct()
{

    parent::__construct();      
    $this->load->model('customerlookup_model');
    $this->load->helper('url');

}

public function index()
{
    echo 'test';
}
public function loadcustomers()
{
    $data['cust'] = this->customerlookup_model->get_customers();
    $this->load->view('customerlookup',$data);
}
```

}

Comment: try to remove your url helper file pages will go blank

Comment: Yeah...that's not how it works. The URL helper is just a set of URL functions that get included into the page. The OP is not using any of those functions so loading it will have no effect whatsoever. Anyway, OP found out it was a syntax error as stated above, you know **2 months *before*** you posted your answer.